# is it possible to transform a vector from a space to another one?

Tags: euclidean-geometry, transformation, noneuclidean-geometry

If I get it right, vectors' transformation is about changing the base, but the vector remains in the same space. Does is make sense to talk about transforming a vector from a space to another different space, not just the base. For example, transforming a vector from an euclidean space to a non-euclidean one?

Comment: Yes, absolutely.  As for examples, take any linear transformation who is represented by a non-square matrix.

Comment: The only condition a linear transformation has to satisfy is preserving addition and scalar multiplication, i.e., $f(a+b)=f(a)+f(b),\;c\cdot f(a)=f(ca)$. It doesn't matter whether the $+$ means radically different things on both sides of the equality.

Comment: Invertible linear transformations of a vector space onto itself can be interpreted as “about changing the base,” but there are plenty of other types of transformations. For instance, the transformation that maps every vector to $0$ is also a linear transformation, but it’s got nothing to do with a change of basis. Also, “euclidean” and “non-euclidean” aren’t, strictly speaking, vector space concepts. These are additional sets of properties with which a vector space might be endowed.